# Nested FlatList with the same scroll direction not scrolling

Tags: react-native

Nested FlatList is not scrolling if it has the same orientation as it's parent FlatList. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 15):

Try using FlatList from [react-native-gesture-handler](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/gesture-handler/) as nested.

```
import { FlatList } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'
```

Comment: Why this one works but not the basic one ?

Comment: You're my hero!

Comment: Damn, man! 2 days of trying to fix and this was the solution. The issue with 'react-native' flatlist still persists.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `nestedScrollEnabled` prop - https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#nestedscrollenabled

Comment: I tried it but it only works if their orientation is different.

Comment: Sorry I missed the same orientation part. Scrolling won't work as you expected for nested FlatList. I think what you are looking for is SectionList. Or maybe if you can setup some example on snack.expo.io, that will helpful for me to give more suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but still an issue... If you wrap the inner FlatList in a ScrollView then it'll scroll.

After doing this I've had issues getting the inner FlatList to respond to refreshing and onEndReached (because it doesn't actually scroll itself) but depending on your use-case this might not be too much of an issue.

Answer (score 0):

import { FlatList } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'

Issue link - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15375